Помогите разобраться как работает структура
решал простые задачки на LeetCode ну и наткнулся на следующую задачку где фигурирует вот такая вот структура.
struct ListNode {
      int val;
      ListNode *next;
      ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
      ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
      ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
};

Из условий я понял что эта задачка создает грубо говоря список. И мне необходимо объединить 2 таких списка. Я пытался обращаться через оператор [] что бы получить значение из списка, но не получилось. Помоги те понять как работает эта структура. Хочу понять как с ней взаимодействовать

Это вопрос из разряда "я не понимаю как устроен язык". Берите учебник и учите C++. Через две недели поймёте, что на ваш вопрос нормального ответа нет.

Или так: структуру можно конструировать, к её полям val и next можно обращаться - читать и писать. Всё. Вам доступны только эти операции. Если вы знаете что такое связный список, вы умеете с ним работать.

оператор [] служит для обращения к элементу массива или подобного ему контейнера по индексу. "Я пытался" - вместо этой мутной фразы приводите конкретный код. "не получилось" - а вместо этой мутной фразы приводите конкретное ожидаемое и фактическое поведение при конкретных входных данных.

Начните с учебника по алгоритмам и структурам данных.

Итак, по пунктам:
1.
Чтобы объединить два связных списка, нужно дойти до последнего элемента 1-го списка и в его поле next записать адрес 2-го списка.
Пример реализации:
void union_list(ListNode* L1, ListNode* L2) {
    ListNode* ptr = L1;
    while (ptr->next != nullptr)ptr = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = L2;
}




Естественно у вас не получилось обратиться к элементу структуры через [].
Точно также вы не сможете сложить две структуры или умножить одну на другую. Чтобы эти операции были возможны, вам надо самостоятельно определить их поведение через перегрузку операторов.
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode* next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode* next) : val(x), next(next) {}
    int operator[](unsigned index)
    {
        ListNode* ptr = this;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)ptr = ptr->next;
        return ptr->val;
    }
};

Теперь при обращении через [i] будет возвращаться i-й элемент в структуре, если считать за нулевой тот нод, к которому применена операция.
Но следует учитывать, что такая операция имеет асимптотику O(i), где i - индекс элемента.
3.
Взаимодействие со структурой:
Пусть у нас есть структура ListNode a.
обращение к первому элементу структуры - a.val`;
ко второму - a.next->val;
к третьему - a.next->next->val;
и тд.
добавить элемент в a - x.next = new ListNode; где x - последний нод объекта а
вставить элемент y после нода x -
y.next = x.next;
x.next = &y;

